# How can I break apart a mountain in Blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, add-on, rigid-body-simulation

I need the top of a mountain to be smashed into pieces when somethings falls and smashes into it. I made the mountain itself using the ANT landscape add-on in blender.
[image]

I tried to break it apart using the cell fracture add-on but I can't figure it out.

Can someone please let me know how I can use the cell fracture add-on in this situation or if there is a better way to go about this.

Comment: you can *break* it by adding a subdivision surface modifier, and setting the number of subdivisions to something like 999. I speak for experience here - doing that will break a lot more than just a mountain :)

Comment: Probably not the type of "break" that you meant though -

Comment: [Fracture Modifier Tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=vid&q=fracture%20modifier%20tutorial)

Comment: @X-27 Judging by his face count in his image, 999 subdivisions would give him 126770850718706813293168277908033756265824209076123280560738922786616981751638568204483057181637039793045211185613800702130163640063694254419394210691141011464980377514796553962760515496529245544788249736078598337175620714185159712052430094302580924736974751949695012644896212779048979557835355725688542830106164100855189858960867308150658308135467133472948683349651620910770875279208689988298203933364693666280766955074951098230656823150801892287188873068442994794080756636750536...

Comment: @X-27 ...3820386044930607426579493532969082710800456263125250159029860188017567740005874571391254285418453986 565557715164033962007855104 (44166*4^999) faces. ;-)

Comment: @X-27 I don't want my blender to break :), I just need the mountain top to be smashed.

Comment: @ScottMilner Yep! that would absolutely break it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try out the Fracture Modifier Build

from here... http://df-vfx.de/fracturemodifier/

or here http://graphicall.org/1148

which is a separate blender build.

I closed the bottom of the landscape with a face, then I prefractured this with a helper object and Voronoi + Boolean. After that i set up some easily breakable constraints and triggering, and added a ground plane.

Simulation looks like this:

[image: Crushed Mountain Top]

If you have further questions, please post either here on stackexchange or here :

https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?343637-Custom-Build-Blender-Fracture-Modifier

The Blend link: (will only work with the Fracture Modifier Build)

[image]

Comment: Will downloading this blender build cause any trouble with the normal blender? I'm a bit nervous about this. Is there any way that I can do this with out a new blender build?

Comment: well, you could still try to close the shape with a bottom face and apply cell fracture, but then you will see cracks all over the place, have many objects etc. You could also try to create a folder named "config" right under the 2.78 folder of your unzipped Fracture Modifier Build. This way ALL settings, addons, startup blend will be looked up in this folder first and created there if necessary. This is a completely isolated build then. But note, if you delete this build again including its config folder, the settings for this build are gone, too. FM build is compatible to 2.78c release.